# Are they equivalent between implicit ctor, no-parameter-empty-body ctor and explicit default ctor?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, standards, semantics

```
struct A1
{
    int n;        
};

struct A2
{
    int n;
    A2(){}        
};

struct A3
{
    int n;
    A3() = default;        
};
```

**Question 1:**

Does the C++ standard guarantee the classes `A1`, `A2`, `A3` are completely equivalent to each other?

**Question 2:**

```
A1 a1;
A2 a2;
A3 a3;
```

Will the compiler not zero-initialize `a1.n`, `a2.n`, `a3.n` as per the C++ standard?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that.. they're not equal since e.g. the first is an aggregate while the second isn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's one difference that `A1` and `A3` are [aggregate type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization), while `A2` is not, because it has a user-defined constructor.

> class type (typically, struct or union), that has
>
> - ...
> - no user-provided`, inherited, or explicit (since C++17)` constructors `(explicitly defaulted or deleted constructors are allowed) (since C++11)`
> - ...

It means for `A1` and `A3` they could be aggregate initialized, while `A2` can't.

```
A1 a1{99}; // fine;  n is initialized to 99
A3 a3{99}; // fine;  n is initialized to 99
A2 a2{99}; // error; no matching constructor taking int found
```

> Will the compiler not zero-initialize `a1.n`, `a2.n`, `a3.n` as per the C++ standard?

According to the rule of [default initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization), if they're of automatic storage duration, no zero-initialization here, all values will be indeterminate. On the other hand, static and thread-local objects get [zero initialized](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization).

Answer (score 2):

They're not equal since they are different entities and have different initializations: the first and last one are aggregates, the second isn't

> An aggregate is an array or a class (Clause 9) with **no user-provided constructors (12.1)**, no brace-or-equal-initializers for non-static data members (9.2), no private or protected non-static data members (Clause 11), no base classes (Clause 10), and no virtual functions (10.3).

Read more about this here: [What are Aggregates and PODs and how/why are they special?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4178175/1938163)

So aggregate initialization works for `A1` and `A3`, it doesn't for `A2`

```
struct A1
{
    int n;        
};

struct A2
{
    int n;
    A2(){}        
};

struct A3
{
    int n;
    A3() = default;        
};


int main()
{
   A1 obj1{42};
   //A2 obj2{42}; // error
   A3 obj3{42};


   return 0;
}
```

> A1 a1;
>      A2 a2;
>      A3 a3;
>
> Will the compiler not zero-initialize a1.n, a2.n, a3.n as per the C++ standard

The variables will be [default initialized](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization).